# binary data manipulation in java

Tags: java, binary-data

I spent the better part of a day chasing down a binary reconstruction bug, and want to understand why:

the specific line of code looked like this (`dataBuffer` is an array of bytes):

```
short data = (short) ((short)dataBuffer[curPos + 3] << 8 | ((short)dataBuffer[curPos + 2]));
```

it sporadically returned garbage until i added a mask to the low-order word:

```
short data = (short) ((short)dataBuffer[curPos + 3] << 8 | (((short)dataBuffer[curPos + 2])) & 0xff);
```

so, my interpretation is that the type-cast from `byte` to `short` occasionally leaves behind trash in the high-order word, causing issues when it's or-ed... but that doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

this code is taken from c++ and worked great there... what am i missing?

Comment: The sign bit of byte need to be reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sign extension. All `byte` values in Java are signed, so any byte value greater than 127 is actually a negative number. Thus, a byte value of, say, 0x90 (= 144 decimal) is actually treated as -112 when it is a `byte`. When it is widened to a `short` it becomes 0xff90 (still -112). You need to mask the value with 0xff to recover the desired bit pattern of `0x0090`.

As an aside, your can eliminate a couple of casts from your second expression:

```
short data = (short) ((dataBuffer[curPos + 3] << 8) | (dataBuffer[curPos + 2] & 0xff));
```

Those casts are, in fact, quite useless. Operands to bitwise operators are always promoted to `int` values<sup>1</sup> before the operator is applied.

<sup>1</sup> Or `long`, if any of them are `long`.

Comment: But removal of the bit 7 loose the original value, no?

Comment: *sigh* ok, that makes sense.

Comment: @Aubin - where is bit 7 being removed?